# How can i export payroll using html table with format to excel file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, export-to-excel

I'm making a payroll generator system and i don't know how to export the designed payroll html file to a excel file? Can someone help me what i have to do or to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the awesome plugin that call [**Datatables**](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html) , the plugin allows us to export the HTML table data into Excel,PDF ,TEXT. Thats easily configurable.

Or you can try to use this simple function

```
function exportPdf(elem) {
  //select your table first
  const table = document.getElementById("table");
  const html = table.outerHTML;
  const url = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + escape(html); // Set your html table into url 
  elem.setAttribute("href", url);
  elem.setAttribute("target", "__blank");
  elem.setAttribute("download", "export.xls"); // Choose the file name
  return false;
}
```

and call the function to a link

```
<a onclick="exportPdf(this)">Export to excel</a>
```